# how to use RSA encryption in swift?

Tags: ios, swift3

I implement the https://github.com/TakeScoop/SwiftyRSA in my project using pods but it give me error [image]

how to solve this? Any other pod please suggest me too.

## Pod file

[image]

Comment: Do you have any other pods in your project?  What version of Xcode are you using? That is a very strange message for some very standard Swift code

Comment: no other pods used. Xcode 8.3.2.

Comment: Try a clean or deleting derived data?  I just pulled the repo and ran the tests OK.  What version of the POD do you have?

Comment: installed SwiftyRSA (0.3.0). I didn't understand "deleting derived data"

Comment: You should be using version 1.2.0.  Do you really need to support iOS 8.0?  Change your platform to 8.3 and run `pod update`

Comment: yes, I want to use this app in iOS 8. how to use version 1.1.1

Comment: Thanks It solved by changing platform to 8.3 and pod to 1.0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version 8.0 of iOS has some serious issues.  I would suggest that you target iOS 8.3 as a minimum.  If you change your `platform` line in your Podfile to iOS 8.3 and run `pod update` then you will get SwiftyRSA 1.2.0 which will resolve your issue.